# Not able to create war file using jenkins

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jenkins, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am not able to crate a war file of my maven project using jenkins.
Can anyone help me to to describe the proper steps required to create a war file using jenkins. 
i am using tomcat7, apache-maven-3.3.9, and jenkins .
I have also insatalled the deploye plugin in jenkins. 
    E:\software\tomcat-7\tomcat7\conf\tomcat-user

```
E:\software\tomcat-7\tomcat7\webapps\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf\settings.xml

<server>
  <id>TomcatServer</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>password</password>
</server>
```

pom.xml--

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.java.ex</groupId>
<artifactId>springtest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>springtest</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc --
>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
 </project>
```

Please let me know the solution...I an new to jenkins...

Comment: the creation of the war file has nothing to do with jenkins. This is done by maven. Can you create the war file locally with maven.?

Comment: Remove <packaging>jar</packaging> from pom.xml and try again.

Comment: I added the following code in pom.xml and it worked....

Answer (score 0):

```
I added the following code in pom.xml and it worked....

<plugins>
 <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.2</version>
       <executions>
                 <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-node-modules-artifact</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>

                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
           <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                 <executions>
             <execution>
               <id>copy_package</id>
                  <phase>install</phase>
             <goals>
   <goal>run</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
   <tasks>
   <copy file="target/springtest.war"
         todir="E:/software/tomcat-7/tomcat7/webapps"/></tasks>
 </configuration>
         </execution>
   </executions>
   </plugin>

</plugins>

  </build>
  <distributionManagement>
   <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>plugins-releases</name>
    <url>http://serverip:8081/artifactory/plugins-release-local</url>
   </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
    <id>snapshots</id>
    <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
    <url>http://serverip:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
      </distributionManagement>
```